# Is there a better way to do this than using tabular?

Tags: tables, arrows

I am wondering if there is a better way to point to the median using an \uparrow (or maybe another arrow/method) with text underneath/accompanying it. I had to put this construct in a table to get things to lineup.

```
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
    $\underbrace{2\quad 9\quad 10\quad 12}_\text{4 elements}$& $\underbrace{19\quad 22}$&$\underbrace{37\quad 39\quad 46\quad 50}_\text{4 elements}$\\
    &   $\Big\uparrow$ &\\
    &&\\
    &$\text{Median}=\frac{19+22}{2}=20.5$&\\
\end{tabular}
```

Here is the output of the above code snippet:

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\substack` and `\mathclap` to pretend the large subscript has no width.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\underbrace{2\quad 9\quad 10\quad 12}_{\text{$4$ elements}}
\quad
\underbrace{19\quad 22}_{
  \substack{
    \big\uparrow\\[3pt]
    \mathclap{\text{Median}=\frac{19+22}{2}=20.5}
  }
}
\quad
\underbrace{37\quad 39\quad 46\quad 50}_{\text{$4$ elements}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\operatorname` is no substitute for `\mathrm` or `\text`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just placing an `array` below the `underbrace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Compute the median according to the above algorithm
\[
\underbrace{2\quad 9\quad 10\quad 12}_{4\text{ elements}}
\underbrace{19\quad 22}_{\begin{array}{c}
    \Big\uparrow \\[6pt] \operatorname{Median} = \frac{19+22}{2} = 20.5
\end{array}}
\underbrace{37\quad 39\quad 46\quad 50}_{4\text{ elements}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Vincent. You're solution is also neat and I'll use it as well.